# Перестала очищаться память после перехода от консольного приложения к Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется исходное консольное приложение. Нужно сделать простой интерфейс в Windows Forms. Я просто скопировал все классы из консольного приложения. Во время работы алгоритма почему-то перестала очищаться память, в консольной версии такой проблемы не было.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public GroupsSettingsForm GroupsSettingsForm { get; set; }
        public SettingsForm SettingsForm { get; set; }
        public DisciplinesSettingsForm DisciplinesSettingsForm { get; set; }
        public ProfessorsSettingsForm ProfessorsSettingsForm { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        //куча статических полей 

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
    }


        private void Btn_StartAlgorithm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    

        }
    }
```

Обработчик нажатия по кнопке. По нажатию начинается работа алгоритма из консольного приложения.

```
private void Btn_StartAlgorithm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {    
                if (FilePath != null)
                {
                    var studyLoad = new Excel(FilePath);
                    studyLoad.GetAllGroups();
                    for (int i = StartSheetIndexWithInfo; i <= EndSheetIndexWithInfo; i++)
                    {
                        studyLoad.GetDisciplines();
                        studyLoad.GetProfessors();
                        studyLoad.GetClasses();
                    }

                    var allClasses = new List<Class>();
                    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
                    {
                        allClasses = db.Classes.ToList();
                        Console.WriteLine(allClasses.Count);
                        allClasses = CombineClasses();
                        Console.WriteLine(allClasses.Count);

                        for (int i = 0; i < allClasses.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var c = allClasses[i];
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", i, c.FreedomGrade, c.Discipline.TypeOfClass.IsLab);
                        }
                    }

                    var rand = new Random();
                    var population = new GeneticAlgorithm(rand, 100, allClasses, 1, 4, 3, 2, WeeksCount);
                    var solution = population.AlgorithmStart();
                }
                else
                {
                    string message = "Необходимо указать путь до Excel-файла с учебной нагрузкой.";
                    string caption = "Ошибка";
                    MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                    DialogResult result;
                    result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
                }
            }
```

При этом, возможно, нужно отметить, что алгоритм долгий и выполняется несколько минут. Программа, естественно, виснет до конца работы алгоритма. По окончании работы алгоритма память все еще не освобождается. Код из обработчика нажатия по кнопке - это код из Main-метода консольного приложения.

И во время отладки вылезает следующее предупреждение:

Помощник по отладке управляемого кода "ContextSwitchDeadlock" 
  Сообщение = Помощник по отладке управляемого кода "ContextSwitchDeadlock" : "CLR не удалось перейти из COM-контекста 0x13d9408 в COM-контекст 0x13d9350 за 60 секунд. Наиболее вероятно, что поток, владеющий контекстом/апартаментом назначения, находится в режиме ожидания или выполнения очень длительной операции без прокачки сообщений Windows. Обычно эта ситуация отрицательно влияет на производительность и даже может привести к зависанию приложения или чрезмерному расходованию памяти. Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, все потоки однопоточного апартамента (STA) должны использовать примитивы ожидания для прокачки (например, CoWaitForMultipleHandles) и периодически прокачивать сообщения во время длительных операций."

На самом деле что-то, вроде, собирается, но явно не в том объеме, который нужен.
[image: Занятая память]

Comment: Почему форма виснет, это понятно: длительные вычисления в GUI-потоке. Нужно их вынести в отдельный поток. А причину потребления памяти так просто сказать не могу, нужно больше информации знать. Хотя, одна из причин указана в предупреждении: вероятно, скапливаются сообщения в очереди сообщений Windows. Пока обработчик клика не завершится, message pump не может _прокачать_ эти сообщения. Думаю, с введением дополнительного потока исчезнет и эта проблема

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а сборщик мусора работает через очередь оконных сообщений? Или почему? Как он вообще с ней связан?

Comment: @Qwertiy - Я сам о таком варианте развития событий только узнал. Так написано в предупреждении отладчика. Я могу лишь предположить, что виндовые сообщения накапливаются в очереди, пока message loop не может их обработать. Очередь растёт и потребляет много памяти. Вероятно, так.

Comment: Ага, нашёл: [contextSwitchDeadlock MDA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/contextswitchdeadlock-mda). Цитата: Memory usage increasing over time is caused by the finalizer thread attempting to call Release on an unmanaged COM component and that component is not returning. This prevents the finalizer from reclaiming other objects.

Comment: Оказалось, вовсе не очередь сообщений растёт, а финализатор не может отработать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ага, интересно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, введение потоков помогло, теперь сборщик работает как надо. Заодно понял, как быть с выводом сообщений о текущем состоянии алгоритма в TextBox на главной форме.

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Settings.Initialize();
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        PrepareDBToWork();
    }


private void Btn_StartAlgorithm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrepareDBToWork();

        if (Settings.FilePath != null)
        {
            //Выгрузка данных из файла

            var allClasses = new List<Class>();
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                allClasses = db.Classes.ToList();
                allClasses = CombineClasses();
            }

            var rand = new Random();
            var population = new GeneticAlgorithm(rand, 100, allClasses);

            //Вывод сообщения в TextBox из главной по форме после того, как произошло событие
            population.IterationDone += IterationDoneMessage;
            population.TempInd += TempIndMessage;
            population.SearchDone += SearchDoneMessage;
            population.ElapsedTime += ElapsedTimeMessage;

            //Создание потока
            var thread = new Thread(population.AlgorithmStart);
            thread.Start(context);

            //Получение наилучшего решения
        }
        else
        {
            //Сообщение об ошибке
        }
    }

    private void IterationDoneMessage(int index)
    {
        TextBox_ConsoleOutput.Text = "Итерация " + index + " закончена.";
    }

    private void TempIndMessage(int quality)
    {
        TextBox_ConsoleOutput.Text += "Текущее качество решения = " + quality + ". ";
    }

    private void SearchDoneMessage(Individual ind)
    {
        TextBox_ConsoleOutput.Text = "Качество решения = " + ind.ScheduleQuality + ". ";
    }

    private void ElapsedTimeMessage(string time)
    {
        TextBox_ConsoleOutput.Text += "Время, затраченное на поиск решения = " + time;
    }
```